# Basic CSS layout

Tags: css

I have a page with a container div 900px wide, margin is auto. I have a header tag within this 150px high.

I want the header to consist of ann image on the left, some text and then another image on the right (opposite the imagine on the left). When I put two img tags in the header div, the second image is on lower than the first. I've tried amending to an inline display without any luck.

Any ideas?

CSS

```
html, body {
    background-color: #ccd6cc;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;   
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, Sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #666666; 
}


.hidden {
    display: none;
}


#page-container {  
    width: 900px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: white;
}



#header {
    height: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
}


#content {
    line-height: 18px; 
}

img#mcclogo {   
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

img#bactulogo {
    display:inline;
    float:right;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<script type="text/javascript" src="curvy.corners.trunk.js"></script>
<head>
    <title>Intranet Layout</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test_layout.css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="page-container">
    <div id="header">
    <img id="mcclogo" src="../images/logo.gif" alt="xx" width="244" height="48" />  
    <img id="bactulogo" src="../images/bactu3.gif" alt="xx" width="260" height="124" /> 
    </div>  



    <div id="content">
    Content 
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It would really be helpful if you post your relevant code and perhaps a demo on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: have you tried to float them ?

Comment: update your post with HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming html is correct, http://jsfiddle.net/sbAvB/

css should be something like this then:

```
#main{
    width:900px;
    margin: auto; }

#header{
    height:150px;
    width:100%
}

#picL
{
    float:left;
}

#text{
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    right:50%;
    width:70%;
}

#picR
{
    float:right;
    margin-right:0px;   }​
```

Likely the issue is a lack of a position/margin variables set in the css properties. To align multiple objects in a line, one way to do this is.

Comment: I've amended my code so it's very similar to this, but still no luck. The second image (the right hand one) stil displays lower than then the left.

Comment: Then likely what is happening is your html objects are inheriting css elements from other, larger objects containing them. Best solution in my opinion, is to download Firebug (an extension for all browsers) that allows you to right click your page and 'inspect element' to view the css on everything. You can edit it there until it's correct, then copy over that changed code in your dev environment.

Comment: I've copied code into a Fiddle, and it displays pefectly, but not in IE8 I'm afraid!

Comment: * When I throw your html into jsfiddle with my css, the 'content' isn't centered, but the right image is to the right. It has to be other css code affecting those elements, since isolated, the right image is swinging right as desired.

Comment: IE8 = the devil. It always causes issues. Best suggestion I can make for overall ie8 issues is in javascript you can detect the browser the user is using, and if ie8 (yes, you can specify) you tweak the css from the javascript code. Really really easy to do if you're familiar with jQuery.

Comment: -- Granted fewer people use IE8 these days anyways, outside of corporations, so unless this is for work and required to work in ie8, I wouldn't worry too much about it. Focus on larger problems first, look for ie8 fixes later.